# Validar 2 perfis diferentes de usuário no Spring Security

Tags: spring

Boa tarde, estou tentando validar dois perfis de acesso no Spring Security. O perfil Admin e o TecnicoSup, cada perfil deve ser direcionado para uma tela Home diferente. Somente está efetuando correto o perfil Admin. Utilizei como exemplo este questionameno feito anteriormente que é bem o que quero fazer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48854004/spring-security-two-roles-implementation .
Alguém poderia me ajudar a fazer a validação dos dois perfis?

```
package br.com.sgis.configuration;
```

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
private String usersQuery;

@Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
private String rolesQuery;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.
        jdbcAuthentication()
            .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
    .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/cadastro").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/recuperarSenha").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/atualizarSenha").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/atualizarSenha/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/tecnico/**").hasAuthority("TECNICOSUP")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .successHandler(this.getSuccessHandler())
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and().logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");

}


private AuthenticationSuccessHandler getSuccessHandler() {
    return (AuthenticationSuccessHandler) new RoleBasedAuthenticationSuccessHandler(
             "/admin/home",
             "/tecnico/home",
               "ROLE_ADMIN"                
            );
}


@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
       .ignoring()
       .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/assets/**");
}
```

}

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

public class RoleBasedAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler
implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

private String adminRoleTargetUrl;

private String adminRoleAuthority;

/**
* @param defaultTargetUrl
*/
public RoleBasedAuthenticationSuccessHandler(String defaultTargetUrl, String adminRoleTargetUrl, String adminRoleAuthority) {
super(defaultTargetUrl);
this.adminRoleTargetUrl = adminRoleTargetUrl;
this.adminRoleAuthority = adminRoleAuthority;
System.out.println("adminRoleTargetUrl..." + this.adminRoleTargetUrl );
System.out.println("this.adminRoleAuthority..." + this.adminRoleAuthority );
}
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler#onAuthenticationSuccess(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, org.springframework.security.core.Authentication)
 */
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("entrou aqui...isAdmin" + isAdmin(authentication) );
    if(isAdmin(authentication)){
        System.out.println("entrou no if"  );
        this.getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, this.getAdminRoleTarUrl());
        return;
    }
    super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
}

/**
 * @param authentication
 */
protected boolean isAdmin(Authentication authentication) {
    for(GrantedAuthority authority : authentication.getAuthorities()){
        if(authority.getAuthority().equals(this.getAdminRoleAuthority())){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * @return the adminRoleTargetUrl
 */
public String getAdminRoleTarUrl() {
    return adminRoleTargetUrl;
}

/**
 * @return the adminRoleAuthority
 */
public String getAdminRoleAuthority() {
    return adminRoleAuthority;
}

}

Answer (score 1):

Consegui descobrir o problema, substitui o ROLE_ADMIN por ADMIN e funcionou:

```
private AuthenticationSuccessHandler getSuccessHandler() {
    return (AuthenticationSuccessHandler) new RoleBasedAuthenticationSuccessHandler(
             "/admin/home",
             "/tecnico/home",
               "ADMIN"                
            );
}
```